# How to understand AS_IF in autoconf?

Tags: autoconf

The document says

> ```
> Macro: AS_IF (test1, [run-if-true1], ..., [run-if-false])
> ```
>
> Run shell code test1. If test1 exits with a zero status then run shell code run-if-true1, else examine further tests. If no test exits with a zero status, run shell code run-if-false, with simplifications if either run-if-true1 or run-if-false is empty.

The configure.ac file contains

```
AS_IF([test "$have_hdf5" != "no"], [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_HDF5], [], [we have HDF5 library + headers])])
```

But when I type in the run shell code test1, i.e. test `"$have_hdf5" != "no"`, nothing appeared. No matter what I entered (such as `test $have_hdf5`), I got nothing. But it actually works when I `./configure`. So how does the `AS_IF` and the `test1` shell code work? Is it testing some environment variables?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're doing, and what you mean by "Run shell code". Please format your question and explain clearly what you're doing. AS_IF(..) is not shell shell script but rather macros written in the M4 language, configure.ac is processed by the automake/autoconf tools and in this case produces the "configure" shell script.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm new to Linux so I don't know how the autoconf and the configure process works. Should I learn the M4 language to understand those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test` utility doesn't have visible output unless you supply an erroneous expression.

`test` will exit with a 0 status if the expression was true and a nonzero exit status indicates the expression was false (or invalid).

`AS_IF` tests the exit status of the expression you supply as its first parameter.

If it was 0 (true), the associated block of code is executed. If not, it moves on to the next test expression and performs with the same behavior.

This happens until the macro runs out of tests. Once all tests are found false, it executes the last parameter's contents if the last parameter was supplied.

**Edit**

Naturally if you don't have "have_hdf5" defined in your current shell, it won't be true when you execute your `test` expression alone, but if it is true in the configure script, it will do what it is meant to. In any case, output will not happen unless you use an output statement.

Comment: What does have "have_hdf5" defined in my current shell mean? Is that a environment variable? Anyway, it's much clear now and thanks for your detailed explanation!

Comment: @Asgard Yes, it would be an environment variable. The environment of the interactive session is unaffected by the configure script's execution. This means no matter what environment variables are set in the configure script, you can't access them outside of the script, unless of course they were set before the configure script was executed; they will have the same value before and after the script's execution in that case.

Comment: That helps a lot! How can I view all the environment variables in my bash? Will printenv or set work? My system now is equipped with hdf5, so I should have "have_hdf5" defined. But I didn't see a have_hdf5 from the output of printenv or set. I just want to figure out where is that precious "have_hdf5".

Comment: @Asgard Basically the configure script works by detecting certain features. In this case, if hdf5 is detected, "have_hdf5" is set within the configure script's environment. You will not see "have_hdf5" by typing `set` in an interactive shell before or after the configure script finishes executing because that variable only exists within the configure script and only after the test(s) used to detect the feature.

Answer (score 0):

The `AS_IF` M4sh macro will expand out to a portable Bourne shell `if` statement (when processed by `autoconf` in the process of writing `configure`), something like:

```
if test1 ; then run-if-true1 ... else run-if-false fi
```

where the interior tests and actions are wrapped in an `elif ... ; then ...`.

Every other parameter starting from the 0th is tested.  Usually these are some kind of variable test (e.g. `test "$have_hdf5" != "no"`), but don't necessarily need to be.